# Originate LDAP queries with a particular source IP/interface

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am running an LDAP client on an Ubuntu that is multi-homed and the LDAP server is reachable only through a specific interface. So, Is there a way to originate ldapsearch from a specific IP or an interface?

Answer (score 3):

Most applications do not know or care what their network interface is, including ldapsearch. That is left to the operating system network stack.

On this client, define desired IP routing so that the LDAP server is out the interface in question.

Assume the LDAP server is `2001:db8:3462:d::389`, a next hop router out the interface is `2001:db8:3462:2::1`, and you are fine with a static route to just the one subnet. iproute command might look like

```
ip route add 2001:db8:3462:d::389/64 via 2001:db8:3462:2::1
```